# How can improve my code on implementation of DBMS queries in c++?

Tags: c++, database, visual-studio-2010

As part of course learning activity I have been asked to implement DBMS query in (based on) c++. The sample c++ code is:-

```
         class Customer
         {
         public:
             string c_id,name,gender;
             int age,phno;
             friend void ticket_book(ifstream&ib1, ifstream &ib2);
         };

         class Ticket
         {
         public:
             string ticket_no,t_origin,t_dest,j_date;
             int berth,amount;
             string status,aadhar_id,bus_no;
             float t_dept,t_arrival;
             friend void ticket_book(ifstream&ib1, ifstream &ib2);
         };

         void ticket_book(ifstream&ib1, ifstream &ib2, Customer hh[], Ticket ee[])
        {
            int flag;
            for(int i=0; i<13;i++)
        {
        ib1 >> hh[i].c_id >> hh[i].name >> hh[i].gender >> hh[i].age >> hh[i].phno;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<14;i++)
        {
            ib2 >> ee[i].ticket_no >> ee[i].t_origin >> ee[i].t_dest >> ee[i].j_date >> ee[i].berth >> ee[i].amount >> ee[i].status >> ee[i].t_dept >> ee[i].t_arrival >> ee[i].aadhar_id >> ee[i].bus_no;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<13;i++)
        {
            flag=0;
            for (int j=0;j<14;j++)
            {
            if (hh[i].c_id==ee[j].aadhar_id)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            }
            if (flag==0)
            {
            cout << hh[i].c_id <<"\t" << hh[i].name <<"\t" << hh[i].gender << "\t"<<hh[i].age<<"\t"<<hh[i].phno<< endl;
            }
        }

 main()
{
    Customer hh[13];
    Ticket ee[14];
    ifstream ib1("C://Users//xyz//Desktop//customer.txt");
    ifstream ib2("C://Users//xyz//Desktop//ticket.txt");
    cout<<"Retrieve the customer details who has not booked any ticket\n"<<endl;
            ticket_book(ib1,ib2,hh,ee);
            ib1.close();
            ib2.close();
}
```

The above code is for retrieving details of customer who has not booked any ticket. Similarly i have to implement 20+ queries based on my database using c++ concepts. I have used array of objects for storing each tuple of a table. Each table contents are stored in text file. Now i have implemented 10 queries and it has already crossed 500 lines of code Microsoft visual studio IDE. When i build the project it takes more than a minute and even execution is slow as number of queries increase when i implement in above manner.

So help me how can I improve my code to implement the above scenario so that it is efficient in all aspects like memory, time. **Which is the better way to implement DBMS queries in c++?** Help me out. Suggestions and edits are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your program is not large enough to produce significant improvements in speed or size.  Most of the time is spent in I/O.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You should use the profiler to find the bottlenecks in you code, then come back with a more specific question if you don't have an idea how to optimize them.

Comment: You should use a database.  Databases are optimized for tasks like yours.

Comment: BTW, 500 lines of code is not a large amount.  In the industry, it could be the small size of a single software unit (of many).  Are you complaining about the size of your code?  You shouldn't worry about the size of code unless it doesn't fit or it is unmanageable.

Comment: Could you be more specific. What kind of database? Because same queries i have implemented using oracle. But this is same queries using c++ concepts. Thank you.

Comment: One minute to build a project is nothing to worry about.  Some projects take hours to build.  You can speed up the build by placing working code into separate source files.  Compilation is the slowest part of the build.  Linking is much faster.

Comment: Are you implementing a database or are you implementing the front end (GUI) to an existing database?

Comment: Ya placing the working code in source file is very good advice. Thank you.

Comment: Search your database documentation for "prepared statements".  Also, make the best use of your transactions by grouping queries.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. It was really helpful like placing working code in source file, grouping queries.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to speed up your program by reading more data into memory with one request.  For example, instead of reading one variable into memory, then the next, read all of the file into memory, then access from memory.

Another alternative is to use memory mapped files.  This is OS dependent and not all OS support this feature.

Common bottlenecks (in order):

- I/O (data transfers)
- Data formatting (converting from text representation to internal
  representation and vice-versa)
- Division & Modulo
- Branching
- Loading data cache.

In general, you will gain more performance by improving your I/O than by improving the data cache.  However, this depends on the quantity of data and data accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving your problem would be through `linklist`.

Insert and delete operation can easily be performed,which reduces the size of code.

Here is the sample code which you can refer.

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
 public:
  node<T> *head;
 public:
   LinkedList(){
    head=new node<T>;
    head->llink=head;head->rlink=head;
}
void insertRear(T str){
    node<T> *nxt,*temp;
    temp=new node<T>;
    nxt=this->head->rlink;
    temp->a=str;
    nxt->llink=temp;
    this->head->rlink=temp;
    temp->llink=this->head;
    temp->rlink=nxt;
}

 void deletePos(T str){
    node<T> *i,*nxt,*before;
    for(i=head->llink;i!=head;i=i->llink){
        if(str==i->a) goto del;
    }
    del:
    nxt=i->rlink;
    before=i->llink;

    nxt->llink=before;
    before->rlink=nxt;
    delete i;
  }
};

class Cust
{
 private:
string c_id;
string name;

public:
Cust(){}
Cust(string a,string b){
    c_id=a;
    name=b;
}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,Cust &c){} 
friend istream& operator>>(istream &in,Cust &c){}
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<Emp> ll;
    Emp c,c1;
    ifstream fin("Emp.txt");
    while(!fin.eof()){
        fin>>c;
        ll.insertRear(c);
    }
    ll.deleteRear();
    fin.close();
    ll.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using arrays, pointer indexing will make the code run more faster.